How to add native methods in JDK8 source code?
I want to add a new native method called "JVM_NewAllocGen" and use it through "System.newAllocGen()". I have added code as below:
path-to-jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:
JVM_ENTRY_NO_ENV(jint, JVM_NewAllocGen())
  JVMWrapper("JVM_NewAllocGen");
  jint gen = Universe::heap()->new_alloc_gen();
  thread->set_alloc_gen(gen);
  return gen;
JVM_END

path-to-jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.h:
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JVM_NewAllocGen();

path-to-jdk8/jdk/src/share/javavm/export/jvm.h:
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JVM_NewAllocGen();

path-to-jdk8/jdk/src/share/native/java/lang/Runtime.c:
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Runtime_newAllocGen(JNIEnv *env, jobject this){
    return JVM_NewAllocGen();
}

path-to-jdk8/hotspot/make/linux/makefiles/mapfile-vers-debug:
JVM_NewAllocGen;

path-to-jdk8/hotspot/make/linux/makefiles/mapfile-vers-product
JVM_NewAllocGen;

But I got the following error:
[ERROR]   cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method newAllocGen()
[ERROR]   location: class java.lang.System

What modifications should be made to solve this problem?
Thanks.

have you declared the newAllocGen() method in System (as must be done with any method)? public static native int newAllocDen(); or so (the System class should have some examples itself)

@user85421  I have declared the method in System.java., then it worked. Thanks a lot!

You are basically forking Java.
